# Implementation of Ball-Larus algorithm

Tags: llvm

Is an implementation of Ball-larus 'efficient path profiling' algorithm available anywhere?

[An implementation in llvm would be more helpful]

Here is a Citeseer link to the original paper [BL96](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.138.7451&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Have they cut off all the internet search engines from your section of the internet?

Comment: @jonathan , i tried googling but could nt find it. If your search engine finds it,why dont u put it here,which would be helpful to others also.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I came here with the same question as Ramshankar. It's great to see that you're actively discouraging the answer on the basis that it offends your sense of what Stack Overflow is for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There already is an [implementation](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/PathProfiling.cpp?view=markup) of Ball-Larus path profiling in [LLVM](http://llvm.org). Additional patches in this area are being [solicited](http://llvm.org/OpenProjects.html#profileguided).

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure if the question really was about LLVM since the only mention was the tag. If the question isn't just about LLVM, there are many other resources as noted in the other answers.

Comment: The link is dead. Perhaps the code can be found elsewhere? Here is a [GitHub mirror of LLVM](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm).

Answer (score 2):

All that i was able to find is some Pseudo-Code:

```
for all node n in reverse topological order do
  if n is a leaf then
     NumPaths(n) ← 1
  else
     NumPaths(n) ← 0
     for all edge e of the form n → m do
        Val(e) ← NumPaths(n)
        NumPaths(n) ← NumPaths(n) + NumPaths(m)
     end for
  end if
end for
```

Comment: @Ramshankar: this is not a code-supply site.  "Gimme-the-code" used to be a derogatory tag added to questions which demand code.  You are lucky it isn't still in vogue.

Comment: @ramshankar:  People like us usually charge for production-ready code (except for some projects that we participate in), and need better specs than "implement the algorithm".  You should either hire somebody, or try to implement it on your own and ask us for help when you need it.

Comment: @jonathon: this is one of fundamental papers in profiling, its implementation is helpful. I needed the link to it.